# "non-greedy" [<any chars>](word) regexp problem

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, search

consider this sentence (a line in a text file):

```
 mi chiamo [Giorgio Robino](person) ed abito in [corso Magenta 35/4 a Genova](address)
```

I want to search (select/extract) the pattern `<any chars>` inside `[<any chars>](<word>)`.

By example, from text: `[Giorgio Robino](person)`, I want to select `Giorgio Robino`

And from text:
`[corso Magenta 35/4 a Genova](address)`, I want to select `corso Magenta 35/4 a Genova`.

---

I entered these 2 regexp search patterns:

```
/\[\zs.\{-}\ze\](person)
```

```
/\[\zs.\{-}\ze\](address)
```

But, as you can see in the screenshot, it happens that the second search highlights a single selection, as the span:

```
mi chiamo [Giorgio Robino](person) ed abito in [corso Magenta 35/4 a Genova](address)
           ^                                                              ^ 
           |                                                              |
```

Instead I would like to have 2 separated selections:

```
mi chiamo [Giorgio Robino](person) ed abito in [corso Magenta 35/4 a Genova](address)
           ^            ^                       ^                         ^ 
           | selection1 |                       | selection2              |
```

So my regexp fails, being "non-greedy".

May you help me finding the right regexp? Any solution suggested?

BTW, my question is related to the plugin I created:
https://github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim

[image]

Comment: `\[\zs[^\[\]]\{-}\ze\](address)`

Comment: or `\[\zs.\{-}\ze\](.\{-})`

Comment: AH! I understand that your first regexp extends my own, excluding chars `[` and `]` and so relating my plughi Highligt.vim I solve with `:HighlightText \[\zs[^\[\]]\{-}\ze\](person)` and `:HighlightText \[\zs[^\[\]]\{-}\ze\](address)`. Thanks

Comment: Try to match anything until a closing `]`,

Comment: Thanks to @MaximKim :  https://github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim#thanks

Comment: Please add an answer that solved your problem, or encourage the commenters whose answers helped to add their own

Answer (score 1):

I add the answer following @D. Ben Knoble invitation.
What solved is the @Maxim Kim first comment!

The solving regexp is:

```
\[\zs[^\[\]]\{-}\ze\](address)
```

The trick is to exclude chars `[` and `]`. So, relating my plugin [Highligt.vim](https://www.github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim), I solved with

```
:HighlightText \[\zs[^\[\]]\{-}\ze\](person)
```

and

```
:HighlightText \[\zs[^\[\]]\{-}\ze\](address)
```

Special [thanks](https://www.github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim#thanks).